# C# datatable to JSON

Tags: c#, datatable

I get some data from datatable, for example:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 20 |

I would like to construct JSON of this structure:

```json
{
    {
      title: column1
      data:[1 2 3]
    },
    {
      title: column2
      data:[10 15 20]
    },
}
```

Is that possible to do?

Comment: Sure. What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: I just tried to serialize datatable by JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt). But i get JSON constructed like {{column1:1,column2:10},...}

Comment: Well, that is the more natural order of things, since a datatable cannot really have two independent columns as in your json. JSON serialization is nothing more than building an anonymous object with those properties. Can you do that? Build a C# datatructure that looks this way?

Comment: That's the problem. I am learning c# and don't know what to use and how. I could maybe put whole column in array. I think i know how to do that. Could i make a list?

Comment: The JSON you have shown is basically a list of objects having a "string Title" and "int[] Data" property. If you can build that from your datatable, all you have to do is serialize that list.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for leading me to this! I will try.